# How do I calculate turn around time in SSRS query?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report that shows quotes from customers, and I need help on how to calculate the turn around time between two dates.

I haven't tried anything cause I don't know where to start.

I am trying to get the turn around time form the date arrived and the date completed

```
select  dbo.paf.Nombre as 'CustomerName', dbo.Comerciales.Nombre,  dbo.CMSStaff.Login, 
dbo.paf.ShipToContactName, dbo.paf.obra, dbo.AW_QuoteLog.Difficulty, dbo.paf.SubTotal, 
dbo.AW_QuoteLOg.Quote_Returned, dbo.AW_QuoteLog.Bid_Required, dbo.AW_QuoteLog.Timestamp
   from dbo.paf
   left join dbo.Comerciales on dbo.paf.Salesmancode = dbo.Comerciales.Codigo
   left join dbo.CMSStaff on dbo.paf.UserCode = dbo.CMSStaff.accountid
   left join dbo.AW_QuoteLog on dbo.paf.numero = AW_QuoteLog.Order_number and dbo.paf.version = AW_QuoteLog.Version_number
 where dbo.AW_QuoteLog.Timestamp > '2019-01-01' and dbo.Aw_QuoteLog.Quote_Returned is null
 order by dbo.AW_QuoteLog.Timestamp ASC;
```

[Quote log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpJAa.png)

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here?  The `Date Arrived` is the same for all, but the `Estimated Completion Date` is all over the place and sometimes before the `Date Arrived`.  Is there meant to be data in the `Date Completed` column?

Comment: yes there is a date completed column, im trying to get the turn around time, from the date arrived date and the date completed date, the estimated date completed is irrelevant, it is just a esitmate

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the difference between two dates, you can use the `DATEDIFF` function. Just add a new calculated field to your query:

```
DATEDIFF(day, [Date Arrived], [Date Completed]) AS Turnaround
```

Comment: do I put that in the query or do I format it as a expression

Comment: What I meant was doing it in the query. If you want to use an expression in a TextBox, you could use something similar: `=DateDiff("d", Fields!Date_Arrived.Value, Fields!Date_Completed.Value)`.

Comment: Also how do I exclude weekends and holidays from that turnaround expression

Comment: No, sorry. Not in a simple expression. But there are many solutions to this found all over this place.